# TypeScript: Run one class's methods from inside another class

Tags: typescript

I may not be doing this correctly, but here's my setup:

I have 2 classes in 2 files:

```
class-a.ts / classA
class-b.ts / classB
```

Then I have a namespace file (namespace.ts):

```
import { classA } from "./class-a";
import { classB } from "./class-b";

namespace App {
    let a = new classA();
    let b = new classB();
}
```

My question is, how do I call methods available in classA inside classB? Right now, if I try and call `a.exampleMethod();` within b, it can't find the instance name. Shouldn't it be available?

Comment: If `classB` needs to call `classA` methods then it needs to know it, meaning that you'll need to import `classA` in `./class-b`

Comment: A lot of things to consider here.  Are classA and classB related in any way?  SHOULD classA be calling classB? Perhaps the method being called can be static?  Maybe this functionality could be factored out into a helper classC and passed into classB?

Comment: @ToastyMallows Good points. Yes, they are related. classA is the app's functionality and classB is the UI/event handlers etc. So classB calls a lot of classA's methods.

Comment: @PaulRedmond If that's really all that is in classB, I would inject classB into classA via the constructor and have classB have an interface that classA requires on its constructor.  That will make it easier to test both classA and classB without dealing with hidden dependencies inside the class.

Comment: @ToastyMallows Okay I see. Can you give me a code example of that in an answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can sort this out:

- instantiate classA within classB (into a var, a field, depending on the scope you need)
- use a mixin an make classB extend classA using the `extends` keyword

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other answer, you could pass `ClassB` into `ClassA` on the constructor.  The benefit here is that both `ClassA` and `ClassB` can be tested without depending on each other (you could pass a `MockClassB` that implements `IClassB` into `ClassA` to test `ClassA`, for example).

This can be adapted to suit your needs.

```
interface IClassB
{
    SomeMethod(): void;
}

class ClassB implements IClassB
{
    public SomeMethod(): void
    {
        // do something to update the UI
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    private classB: IClassB;

    constructor( classB: IClassB )
    {
        this.classB = classB;
    }

    public SomeFunctionality(): void
    {
        this.classB.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Then somewhere at the root of your application:

```
let iclassB: IClassB = new ClassB();
let classA: ClassA = new ClassA( iclassB );
```